# Django - How to make a Django snipet available to use as template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've found a Django snipet, but I have no idea on how to configure it.

The snippet is this one: https://github.com/r0wb0t/markdown-urlize/blob/master/urlize.py

The documentation says that to install I should:

```
To play nicely with Django, drop urlize.py into your PYTHONPATH or projects root directory as mdx_urlize.py for Django's Markup app to properly load this as an extension.
```

I'm using virtualenv. This means that I should put this file on "myvirtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages"?

And If I put the file in my Django project, I should put the file in "mydjangoproject/myprojectname"? "myprojectname" is the folder where is the **init**.py and settings.py. If I go this way there is the need off register this code as a template tag?

Give me some clues. I'm lost with this one.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It says you use it either in template or in python code. If you want to use it in templates just put it in your templatetags folder. If you want to code it in python just put it together with views.py, models.py ....